# Difference between minimal coupling $(p-qA)$ and $B \cdot L$,In Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, magnetic-fields, quantum-electrodynamics

It seems like when coupling an electron to a magnetic field we always use $B \cdot S$ to couple its spin magnetic moment to the magnetic field.

However sometimes we couple its motion to the magnetic field with $(p-qA)$ and sometimes with $B \cdot L $.

I guess that the former form is more general and can be used even when the electron will not have well defined L, but, other than that, what are the differences?

I would also like to know what is ‘minimal’ about the minimal coupling. What other forms are ‘less minimal’ than the minimal coupling and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of *minimal* in *minimal coupling* refers to the possibility that a system interacts with an electromagnetic field through different multiples. If only the monopole interaction is present, that is called *minimal coupling*.

In the case of the electron, the minimal coupling only takes into account the orbital motion, via the $p-qA$ term in the Hamiltonian. However, that full interaction should also include the presence of the spin. In that case, the non-relativistic Hamiltonian contains an $S \cdot B$ term.

Comment: Ah okay. I was confused since in my lecture notes it said minimal coupling but then included both $(p-qA) $ and $B \cdot S$ but I think it could be bad wording

Comment: @AlexGower It depends on what is the free Hamiltonian. Starting with the relativistic one, the $B\cdot S$ term of the non-relativistic limit (Pauli equation) has the same origin as the orbital coupling. In a way, it is meaningless to speak about minimal coupling without specifying the Hamiltonian that has to be coupled to the em field.